# Salt: Install multiple packages that have been *listed in a file*

Tags: salt-stack, apt-get

Imagine if you had a file like a standard Python [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file) but instead of listing Python packages it listed `apt-get`-able Ubuntu packages. In its simplest form it would just be a list of package names with newlines delimiters:

```
# apt-requirements.txt
git
python3.5
python3.5-dev
libssl-dev
```

Now what if you wanted to install these packages with a `salt` state by looking at the file at runtime? Here's one way I can imagine doing it:

```
apt-requirements.txt_installed:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
{% for line in salt['cmd.run']('cat ' + my_file).splitlines() %}
      - {{ line.strip() }}
{% endfor %}
```

This seems terrible, though. In addition to being ugly, the file has to be present at render time, which is a serious nuisance.

Does anyone have a better recipe?

Comment: Will that file be located in the **salt-minion** or in the **salt-master** ?

Comment: @alejdg The minion

Comment: i have a similar requirement for a Dockerfile, where i use `awk -vORS=" " '{ print $1 }' apt-requirements.txt | xargs apt-get install -y`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by using [cp.get_file_str](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.get_file_str).

As you can see in the following example am trying to install two packages saved on a file located on the minion

```
# yum-requirements.txt
mlocate
screen
```

The state file will be as the following:

```
# packages.sls
{% set packages_to_be_installed = salt.cp.get_file_str('/home/yum-requirements.txt').splitlines() %}

install_packages:
  pkg.latest:
    - pkgs: {{ packages_to_be_installed }}
```

The result:

```
minion01:
----------
          ID: install_packages
    Function: pkg.latest
      Result: True
     Comment: All packages are up-to-date (mlocate, screen).
     Started: 02:09:27.490644
    Duration: 4036.966 ms
     Changes:   

Summary for minion01
------------
Succeeded: 1
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     1
Total run time:   4.037 s
```

Note: I assume that your requirements file doesn't have any commented lines.

Comment: The main issue with your solution is that (as noted in the question) the file `/home/yum-requirements.txt` cannot itself be generated by salt; it must be present at run-time.

Comment: Have you tried to create the file and use require in the pkg.installed to make sure that your file copied to the minion first ?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment should have said "it must be present at *render* time." AFAICT, the only way to accomplish what you're suggesting is with an orchestration runner, which is an awful lot of overhead for a dead-simple use-case.